# Making sure system call is run after all previous system calls

Tags: php, linux, shell

I'm working on a big e-commerce website that relies on multiple scripts to run to update the inventory. I have a single php file that is run on CRON and calls other inventory scripts like below:

```
<?php
//Run these 2 together to save time
exec("SCRIPT1.PHP > SCRIPT1_LOG.TXT & SCRIPT2.PHP > SCRIPT2_LOG.TXT");

system("SCRIPT3.PHP > SCRIPT3_LOG.TXT");

system("SCRIPT4.PHP > SCRIPT4_LOG.TXT");

//I want this script to run AFTER all previous scripts
system("SCRIPT5.PHP > SCRIPT5_LOG.TXT");
?>
```

I need my last script, SCRIPT5.PHP to run AFTER all previous scripts. What's the best way to accomplish this? The way I have it now is not forcing the last one to run last if the previous scripts are taking longer to finish.

Comment: Scripts run sequentially unless you run them in the background or they put themselves in the background.

Comment: Would separating them with & cause them to run in the background?

Comment: in your code above, only `SCRIPT1.PHP` is running in the background. If you want them to run sequentially, replace `&` with `;`. Good luck.

Comment: Uh, yes. `&` is how you put a process in the background.

Comment: @shellter The first two scripts are very long scripts (each take about 7 hours to finish). That's why I'm running them together to save time. But I do still want the last script to run last. I guess I'd have to manually call the last one in a separate CRON job.

Comment: Put all of these scripts into a master script, then you can use `&` like above , but put a `wait` command before `SCRIPT5`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Put all of these scripts into a master script, then you can use & like above , but put a `wait` command before `SCRIPT5`. Good luck. – shellter